# I want to add a floating text on a video in case of full screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I added a text on a video in normal case and it works fine but in full screen case the text disappeared i tried :

```
<div class="homepage-video">
'.$OUTPUT->box($content, "generalbox center clearfix").'
<div class="text-over-video">
  <h1>id: '.$USER->id.'</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

the style :

```
<style>
.homepage-video, .homepage-video video {
    position: relative;
  }
  .homepage-video video {
      background-size: cover !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: 50% !important;
  }
  
  .text-over-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
```

any ideas to appear this text also in full screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing text on full Screen Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432481/showing-text-on-full-screen-video)

Comment: You also need to set z-index to your video .

Answer (score 0):

You should try to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432481/showing-text-on-full-screen-video), and use a video tag.
Otherwise I think it will be complicated to add text on **fullscreen**..